# Integer to Alpha Representation

Tags: performance-tuning, number-bases, digits

I wanted a nice way to convert natural numbers to alphabetic representations like:

```
1->"A",
2->"B",
...
26->"Z",
27->"AA,
...
26*2->"AZ",
26*2+1->"BA",
...
```

And I knew this was mostly a conversion base 26 problem, except with the complication of lacking a `0`

So things like:

```
In[412]:= IntegerDigits[26, 26]

Out[412]= {1, 0}
```

Would cause difficulties.

I solved this by unspooling via [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) where the sequence pattern `{n_,0}` maps to `{n-1,26}`, because, by the way digit representations are defined, `{n,0}` is equivalent to `{n-1,0}` and by having this cascade up / down the chain we get the right answer.

Here's the actual code for this:

```
intToAlpha[i_Integer?Positive, 
   alphabet : {__String} | Automatic : Automatic] :=

  With[{alpha = Replace[alphabet, Automatic :> Alphabet[]]},
   ToUpperCase@StringJoin@
     Part[alpha,
      DeleteCases[0]@
       ReplaceRepeated[IntegerDigits[i, Length@alpha],
        {s___, n_?Positive, 0, e___} :>
         {s, n - 1, Length@alpha, e}
        ]
      ]
   ];
intToAlpha[i : {__Integer?Positive}, 
   alphabet : {__String} | Automatic : Automatic] :=

  With[{a = Replace[alphabet, Automatic :> Alphabet[]]},
   intToAlpha[#, a] & /@ i
   ];
```

And this is decent all told:

```
In[433]:= AssociationMap[
 intToAlpha,
 RandomInteger[{1, 26*26*2}, 100]
 ]

Out[433]= <|1112 -> "APT", 907 -> "AHW", 870 -> "AGL", 938 -> "AJB", 
 1256 -> "AVH", 991 -> "ALC", 25 -> "Y", 203 -> "GU", 433 -> "PQ", 
 994 -> "ALF", 480 -> "RL", 762 -> "ACH", 576 -> "VD", 570 -> "UX", 
 931 -> "AIU", 1090 -> "AOX", 1237 -> "AUO", 404 -> "ON", 695 -> "ZS",
  1180 -> "ASJ", 580 -> "VH", 1040 -> "AMZ", 198 -> "GP", 218 -> "HJ",
  964 -> "AKB", 667 -> "YQ", 1135 -> "AQQ", 1285 -> "AWK", 
 763 -> "ACI", 825 -> "AES", 588 -> "VP", 841 -> "AFI", 1036 -> "AMV",
  1268 -> "AVT", 592 -> "VT", 742 -> "ABN", 118 -> "DN", 599 -> "WA", 
 795 -> "ADO", 119 -> "DO", 640 -> "XP", 809 -> "AEC", 213 -> "HE", 
 289 -> "KC", 1293 -> "AWS", 51 -> "AY", 829 -> "AEW", 37 -> "AK", 
 491 -> "RW", 1340 -> "AYN", 521 -> "TA", 55 -> "BC", 895 -> "AHK", 
 1211 -> "ATO", 1130 -> "AQL", 498 -> "SD", 1038 -> "AMX", 
 753 -> "ABY", 1191 -> "ASU", 542 -> "TV", 92 -> "CN", 168 -> "FL", 
 949 -> "AJM", 317 -> "LE", 354 -> "MP", 1141 -> "AQW", 1310 -> "AXJ",
  857 -> "AFY", 904 -> "AHT", 645 -> "XU", 1065 -> "ANY", 324 -> "LL",
  684 -> "ZH", 903 -> "AHS", 679 -> "ZC", 90 -> "CL", 1101 -> "API", 
 427 -> "PK", 844 -> "AFL", 162 -> "FF", 159 -> "FC", 559 -> "UM", 
 398 -> "OH", 860 -> "AGB", 1216 -> "ATT", 871 -> "AGM", 671 -> "YU", 
 285 -> "JY", 389 -> "NY", 499 -> "SE", 889 -> "AHE", 67 -> "BO", 
 448 -> "QF", 211 -> "HC", 836 -> "AFD", 808 -> "AEB"|>

In[434]:= 
intToAlpha[Range[100000]] // RepeatedTiming // First[#]/100000 &

Out[434]= 0.0000170
```

But I feel like there should be a more elegant (and likely faster) way, no?

Is there a way to do this directly, rather than converting via `IntegerDigits` then converting out the `0`s? Is there some built-in function I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use [`IntegerDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits) directly if you add an offset, and then use the 3rd argument of [`IntegerDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits) to only return the needed digits. For instance, consider base 3. If we use an offset (in trinary notation) of:

$$11 \text{$\cdots $1112}$$

Then the trinary notation for the offset integers $1, 2, \text{$\dots $, 13}$ is:

$$1120, 1121, 1122, 1200, 1201, 1202, 1210, 1211, 1212, 1220, 1221, 1222, \
2000$$

Notice that if we take the last digit of the first 3, the last two digits of the next 9, and then the last 3 digits of the last number, we get:

$$0, 1, 2, 00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 000$$

With the replacements `{0->"a", 1->"b", 2->"c"}` we get the desired alphabet representation. The following code uses this idea:

```
intToAlphabet[i_, alphabet:{__String}|Automatic:Automatic]:=Module[{a = Replace[alphabet,Automatic:>ToUpperCase@Alphabet[]],base,maxDigits,offset,indices},
    base=Length[a];
    maxDigits = Floor[Log[base,(base-1)Max[i]+1.1]];
    offset=(1+(base-2)(base^maxDigits-1)/(base-1)) ;
    indices=1+IntegerDigits[i+offset, base, Floor[Log[base,(base-1)i+1.1]]];
    If[ListQ@i,
        StringJoin[a[[#]]]&/@indices,
        StringJoin[a[[i]]]
    ]
]
```

One comment on the code. Computing `Floor[{Log[3,5], Log[3,15], ..}]` is slow while the almost equivalent `` Floor[{Log[3, 5`], Log[3, 15`], ..}] `` will be very fast. The only issue with using real numbers instead of integers is to make sure something like `` Floor[Log[3, 9`]] `` evaluates to 2 and not 1 due to precision issues. I take care of this by adding a bit of slop.

At any rate, some examples:

```
intToAlphabet[Range[20], {"a","b"}]
```

> {"a", "b", "aa", "ab", "ba", "bb", "aaa", "aab", "aba", "abb", "baa", "bab", 
>   "bba", "bbb", "aaaa", "aaab", "aaba", "aabb", "abaa", "abab"}

```
r = intToAlphabet[Range[10^5]]; //AbsoluteTiming
r[[{285, 448, 211}]]
```

> {0.259129, Null}

in agreement with a few examples in your question.

> {"JY", "QF", "HC"}

Comment: Overall very nice. I had thought about trying to add an offset before, but couldn't quite get it to work. One issue is that, working with `Alphabet[]` it doesn't seem to handle the transition from 1 digit to 2 properly (and there are some oddities further up in the 2-digit sequences). E.g. `{intToAlphabet[{26, 27}]}` gives `{{"Z", "CA"}}` and `{intToAlphabet[{702}], intToAlphabet[{703}]}` gives `{{"BZ"}, {"CAA"}}`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I was tweaking things at the end, and introduced a bug. The problem is that the offset doesn't have enough digits. I think my edit should fix this.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. It's a lot faster than my implementation and just as flexible. Very nice.

Answer (score 5):

A memoized recursive approach seems faster:

```
dictionary = AssociationThread[Range[26] -> CharacterRange["A", "Z"]]

Clear[replace]
replace[n_Integer /; n <= 26] := replace[n] = dictionary[n]
replace[n_Integer] := replace[n] = Module[{quot, rem},
   {quot, rem} = QuotientRemainder[n, 26];
   If[rem == 0, quot = quot - 1; rem = 26];
   If[quot > 0, replace[quot] <> replace[rem], replace[rem]]
 ]
```

Comparative timing tests:

```
nums = RandomInteger[{10000000, 20000000}, 100000];

RepeatedTiming[replace /@ nums;]
(* Out: {0.0944, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[intToAlpha@nums;]
(* Out: {2.34, Null} *)
```

Comment: Very nice. I know this is somewhat auxiliary to what I asked (but still, I think, relevant), but how would you memoize this for an arbitrary `Alphabet`? I'm thinking use a `Block` and memoize via an `Association` and use `Lookup` instead of a function call. The memoization there isn't permanent, but it should still be fast.

Comment: @b3m2a1 The alphabet is coded into `dictionary` and independent of the memoization. You could just hand-code a different one as an explicit association, e.g. `<|1 -> "!", 2 -> "D", ... |>` etc. I wonder if I misunderstand your question though.

Comment: I meant, consider some alphabet `{a,b,c, ..., }` and you want to perform the same sort of translation. Your memoization on `replace` would use `Alphabet[]`, rather than `{a,b,c, ...}`. But it's not so bad using a `Block`, a `memo` association, and localizing `dictionary`.

Comment: One concern, I guess, is that if you don't use the same `nums` each time you lose a lot of the performance gain. For example: `replace /@ 
  RandomInteger[{10000000, 20000000}, 100000] // RepeatedTiming` is about 1.4 seconds for me whereas `intToAlpha@
  RandomInteger[{10000000, 20000000}, 100000] // RepeatedTiming` is 1.8 seconds (and slightly more flexible). If we generalize `replace` to arbitrary dicts it's then not even faster than the `ReplaceRepeated` method.

Answer (score 3):

[`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html) and [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient.html) support offsets, allowing:

```
core = Quotient[Sow @ Mod[#, 26, 1]; #, 26, 1] &;

fn[n_Integer?Positive] := (
  NestWhile[core, n, Positive]
    // Reap
    // Extract[{2, 1}]
    // FromCharacterCode[# + 64] &
    // StringReverse
 )
```

Test:

```
Accumulate[26^Range[4]]

fn /@ %

fn /@ (%% + 1)
```

> ```
> {26, 702, 18278, 475254}
>
> {"Z", "ZZ", "ZZZ", "ZZZZ"}
>
> {"AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "AAAAA"}
> ```

I don't expect this to be competitively fast as written but the algorithm should be compilable.

Comment: Nice. I would be interested in a speed comparison of my algorithm and a compiled version of yours.

Comment: @CarlWoll If you have a C compiler installed please consider trying it.  I tried to install a compiler twice and had trouble both times, so I just sort of gave up.  Maybe start from `Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
 Rest@NestWhileList[{Mod[#[[2]], 5, 1], Quotient[#[[2]], 5, 1]} &, {0, 
     n}, #[[2]] > 0 &][[All, 1]],
 {{_NestWhileList, _Integer, 2}}
 ]`